# .htaccess - remove everything after third slash in path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my website, I only use 3 slashes in my URL path:

```
https://example.com/this/isatest/
```

Right now I use `.htaccess` which makes it possible (as a side effect) to add as many stuff on the URL as you like:

```
https://example.com/this/isatest/hipperdihopperdus/pizza/bacon/with/cheese
```

I'd like to automatically remove everything after "isatest" while keeping the trailing slash using `.htaccess`.

This is what my `.htaccess` currently looks like:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# 301 Redirect all requests that don't contain a dot or trailing slash to
# include a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^listen/$ /console/ [NC,L]

# Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
# but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your first rule, after the `RewriteEngine` directive, you can do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/). /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This checks if there is anything else (the dot) after two path segments and a slash, and redirects to removed "anything else".

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change this to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed that it works OK. This is to avoid the browser caching erroneous redirects whilst testing.

**UPDATE:** It may be more efficient to simply avoid redirecting files that end in a recognised file extension. Or perhaps exclude known directory location(s) of your static resources. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/). /$1 [R=302,L]
```

OR,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static-resources/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/). /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify this so it doesn't affect my CSS/JS files? Possibly by checking if the location doesn't exist (since the URLs are rewritten)?

Comment: Yes, you can add a filesystem check, or simply avoid redirecting requests that end in `.css` (and/or `.js`, `.png`, etc...) I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this rule **just below `RewriteEngine On` line**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/).+$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I wish I could accept both since both answers are useful. :(